# Read slide mode and spell check option

Tags: python-pptx

Do we have an option in python to check the slide mode (fit mode) and what type of spellcheck used in the presentation??? I am developing a code in python which requires me to check all these parameters. Please let me know if there is a way...

Comment: What do you mean by "slide mode (fit mode)"? Maybe describe it by how you make the setting using the PowerPoint application.

Comment: There is an option in powerpoint to fit the slide to window... This option is available in the view section "Fit to Window". Is there a way to read that this option was selected in the ppt?? Also, please help me on the spellcheck query?

Comment: Oh, I think you're talking about Zoom level, one of which is "fit to window". Again though, you've asked two questions here. SO is really designed to ask and answer one question at a time: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: I understand how SO works now... I am new to SO. Let me submit 2 question separately and tag it to you. Thank you.